# Wait until the rest api returns result and then call api again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, axios

Is there any other way other than `setTimeout()` to wait for the result come back after api call and then call that api again immediately after result is received?

In my case, I have to call `n` times times (depending on user input) and the api call takes 20-40 seconds to process and return result from the backend. If I send another request, while the previous one is still being processed in the backed, then it breaks the backend.

What is the right way to do call api once result is received and fully processed?

```
sendRequest() {
    let self = this;
        function f() {
            if (self.state.callPerSite < self.state.selectedSites.length) {
                self.processData(transid);
                   setTimeout(f, 20)
                }
            } else {
                self.setState({progress: 100});
            }
        }
        f();
} 

processData(transid) {
        rest.apiCall({transactionId: transid}, 'json').then(results => {

            if (!firstCallIsProcessed) {
                firstCallIsProcessed = true;
            }
            callPerSite++;

            this.setState({
                resultsData: results.data,
                callPerSite: callPerSite
            });

        }).catch(err => this.onError(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few changes:

- Make your function `processData` return the promise, by just prefixing the `return` keyword:

  ```
  return rest.apiCall(  // ....
  ```
- Chain a call to `f` with the `then` method on that return value without further need for calling `setTimeout`:

  ```
  self.processData(transid).then(f)
  ```

That's it.

Comment: i guess then i dont have to use `setTimeout()` ??

Comment: Indeed, you don't need it.

Comment: btw, the `rest.apiCall` is an axios call, when you say _by just putting the return keyword before rest.apiCall_, <--- why before `rest.apiCall` and not after `this.setState({resultData: results.data})` ??

Comment: You *could* also put a `return` there, but that is for another reason: that would determine the promised value. Without it, the promised value is `undefined`. For your case it is not important, as your main code just looks at the `state` after the promise resolves. The `return` I talk about is needed because otherwise your function does not return a promise at all (it would not return anything), so you would not be able to chain a `then` to it then.  Note difference between "promise" and "promised value".

Comment: `processData(transid) {                                                                          
        return;
        rest.apiCall({transactionId: transid}, 'json')`....}  <-- like this ?? @trincot

Comment: No, that would be quite useless. You need to return the promise that axios provides: `return rest.apiCall( ....`

Answer (score -1):

You want to look at the new **await** and **async** methods.

Check this out: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: .. and by "methods" I really meant "methodology".